# Application loader "new in-app purchases" or only "Deliver your app"?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, ipa, application-loader

The question is simple but i haven't found any answer in google nor the application loader guide.

If I export my archive into an .ipa and submit it to the app store via application loader, and then configure my in-app purchases directly in the Itunes Connect's webpage, do I also have to configure in app purchases with application loader (the button that says "New In-App purchases")?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not. 
The application loader just load in-app purchases from server. 
After you configure in-app purchase in the itunes connect. you can see same in the application loader.

Comment: @josegabriel yes, don't worry,just do it.